# Directive doesn't get controller of parent directive

Tags: angularjs, controller, directive

This [app](http://plnkr.co/edit/hpusDCwXWNl2j2iEzoTn?p=preview) should console.log controller of the 'first' directive, why that doesn't happen? I'm almost sure that this may work fine. 'second' directive get template with 'third' from attrs and append it. 'third' directive require 'first'.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.3" data-semver="1.4.3" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.3/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="myApp">
    <div first>123</div>
  </body>

</html>

angular.module('myApp', [])
  .directive('first', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: postLink,
      template: '<div second="<div third></div>"></div>',
      controller: function() {}
    };

    function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {}
  })
  .directive('second', function($compile) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: postLink
    };

    function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
      var link = $compile(attrs.second);

      element
        .empty()
        .append(link(scope));
    }
  })  
  .directive('third', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      require: '?^first',
      link: postLink,
      template: '<h1>Third</h1>'
    };

    function postLink(scope, element, attrs, FirstCtrl) {
      console.log(FirstCtrl);
    }
  })
```

Comment: where is FirstCtrl ?

Comment: function postLink(scope, element, attrs, FirstCtrl) {
        console.log(FirstCtrl);}

Answer (score 0):

You need to write functionality in controller part of directive

```
.directive('first', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: postLink,
      template: '<div second="<div third></div>"></div>',
      controller: function() {
        console.log('write functionality here');
      }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are compiling your element before appending it to its parent element, so at the time of compilation the element has no parent and obviously no parent controllers.

You need to compile the child element only after appending it to its parent.

```
var child = angular.element(attrs.second)
element.empty().append(child);
$compile(child)(scope);
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/A1sZKQVrWDCsWaraiSNI?p=preview